# Remove .net ContextMenuStrip Padding

Tags: .net, contextmenustrip

When creating a ContextMenuStrip, there is a huge amount of padding around the contained controls.
For example:

```
    Me.myMenu = New ContextMenuStrip
    'unset all obvious padding settings'
    Me.myMenu.ShowCheckMargin = False
    Me.myMenu.ShowImageMargin = False
    Me.myMenu.Margin = New System.Windows.Forms.Padding(0)
    Me.myMenu.Padding = New System.Windows.Forms.Padding(0)

    Dim addButton As New Button
    addButton.Size = New Size(60, 60)
    addButton.Text = "Button"
    Dim addControlHost As New ToolStripControlHost(addButton)

    Me.myMenu.Items.Add(addcontrolhost)

    Me.ContextMenuStrip = Me.myMenu
```

This, ideally, would cause a 60x60 button to pop up at the cursor location.
What actually pops up is this:

[alt text http://img144.imageshack.us/img144/8512/contextmenubutton.png](http://img144.imageshack.us/img144/8512/contextmenubutton.png)

The button is there, as expected, but despite there being no margin, no padding, and having set both Show*Margin settings to False, there is a massive border around the Button.

I'm probably missing something blindingly obvious, but how can I get rid of all the white bordering, especially that huge right-hand margin?

Comment: **This question (Mar '09) is older than the dupe (Dec '11). It is the dupe that should be the actual dupe.**

Comment: Would, except this question has no accepted answer.  Can't reference it in the duplicate question.  And now can't flag this one as a duplicate (again).  Duplicate question:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8610193/remove-white-space-around-toolstripcontrolhost/36201823#36201823

Answer (score -1):

I think setting ShowShortCutKeys = False will get rid of some of the extra right margin.

Comment: ShowShortCutKeys is a property of ToolStripMenuItem, which in this case is not used...

Comment: check this discussion: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-SG/winforms/thread/44a8a77f-99a2-4aaa-947f-1bba07c11b03