# Remove White Space Around ToolStripControlHost

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, winforms

I am trying to remove the white space around a toolstripcontrolhost control which hosts a calendar control in a contextmenu.  See the attached image and code.

VB:

```
    Dim menuItem As ToolStripMenuItem = New ToolStripMenuItem("MyMenu")

    Dim calControl As New MonthCalendar

    Dim controlHost As ToolStripControlHost = New ToolStripControlHost(calControl)

    controlHost.Margin = Padding.Empty
    controlHost.Padding = Padding.Empty

    ContextMenuStrip1.Items.Add(menuItem)
    menuItem.DropDown.Items.Add(controlHost)
```

C#:

```
ToolStripMenuItem menuItem = new ToolStripMenuItem("MyMenu");

MonthCalendar calControl = new MonthCalendar();

ToolStripControlHost controlHost = new ToolStripControlHost(calControl);

controlHost.Margin = Padding.Empty;
controlHost.Padding = Padding.Empty;

ContextMenuStrip1.Items.Add(menuItem);
menuItem.DropDown.Items.Add(controlHost);
```

[image]

Comment: Is there a reason you are using a ContextMenuStrip to do this instead of just a ToolStripDropDown?

Comment: @Lars, the ContextMenuStrip is being used with the right click on a datagridview.

Comment: @Lars, my mistake - I see what you mean now.  Using a toolstripdropdown instead of a contextmenustrip for the **sub menu** itself.  Can you post your comment as a solution please.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A `ToolStripDropDown` will probably work better in this scenario:

```
MonthCalendar calControl = new MonthCalendar();
ToolStripControlHost controlHost = new ToolStripControlHost(calControl);
controlHost.Margin = Padding.Empty;
controlHost.Padding = Padding.Empty;
ToolStripDropDown toolDrop = new ToolStripDropDown();
toolDrop.Padding = Padding.Emtpy;
toolDrop.Margin = Padding.Empty;
toolDrop.Items.Add(controlHost);

toolDrop.Show(this, location);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
ToolStripMenuItem menuItem = new ToolStripMenuItem("MyMenu");

MonthCalendar calControl = new MonthCalendar();

ToolStripControlHost controlHost = new ToolStripControlHost(calControl);

controlHost.Margin = Padding.Empty;
controlHost.Padding = Padding.Empty;

ContextMenuStrip1.Items.Add(menuItem);
ToolStripDropDown dropDown = new ToolStripDropDown();
dropDown.Items.Add(controlHost);
menuItem.DropDown = dropDown;
```

Answer (score 0):

Most of the answers to this question I've found redirect developers to use a `ToolStripDropDown` **INSTEAD** of a context menu strip.  However, for my project, I wanted a drop-down off an already complex context menu.  Earlier in my project, for a different popup needed, I had gotten a simple popup wrapper from here: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/17502/Simple-Popup-Control.  This simple popup was inherited from `ToolStripDropDown`. Here's the core VB code:

```
Public Class PopupBox
    Inherits ToolStripDropDown

    Private mHost As ToolStripControlHost = Nothing

    Public ReadOnly Property Host As ToolStripControlHost
        Get
            Return mHost
        End Get
    End Property

    Public Sub New(content As Control)
        MyBase.New()

        Me.ResizeRedraw = True
        Me.Margin = Padding.Empty
        Me.Padding = Padding.Empty
        Me.AutoSize = True

        Me.mHost = New ToolStripControlHost(content)

        Me.mHost.Margin = Padding.Empty
        Me.mHost.Padding = Padding.Empty
        Me.mHost.AutoSize = True

        Me.Items.Add(Me.mHost)

    End Sub

End Class
```

It turns out that this popup is perfect for use as-is to apply a drop-down (with no padding) to an existing context menu.  Here are the steps:

1. Add a `ToolStripMenuItem` to your context menu as you normally
   would.  In this example, the item is named "ToolStripMenuItem1".
2. In the appropriate location (a constructor or Opening event of the
       context menu), add the following code to replace the DropDown **ENTIRELY**:

`ToolStripMenuItem1.DropDown = New PopupBox(<your control here>)`

Apparently without the inherited object accessing the protected `ResizeRedraw` property AND applying the stated values to the `Margin`, `Padding`, and `AutoSize` properties in the constructor of the `PopupBox`, the `ContextMenuStrip` still applies padding to the left and right of the dropdown.  So there's no shortcut.

**NOTE**: The CodeProject article indicates a [GNU License](http://www.opensource.org/licenses/lgpl-3.0.html), and also that there were some caveats to what could be hosted by PopupBox, so read the article for more details.

Related/Source links:

- http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/17502/Simple-Popup-Control
- http://lukesw.net/articles/SimplePopup.aspx
- http://luminous.codeplex.com/ (see "Popup control" link there)